# Генерация ссылки с одноразовым токеном для входа

Tags: авторизация, html, javascript

Есть ТЗ:
Пользователь получает в письме ссылку на страницу где проходит тест.

1. Как сделать, чтобы генерировалась ссылка с одноразовым токеном для входа?
2. Как сделать, чтобы результат теста отсылался на почту админу?

Код не обязателен.
Просто нужно разжевать алгоритм - чем и что именно делать.

Answer (score 3):

А при чем тут js? Вы когда отправляете письмо, генерируйте на сервере токен, кладите его в базу данных и шлите ссылку на письмо вида: http://my-site.com?token=7i5b7as54vc87. Когда пользователь переходит по ссылке, меняете статус токена на expired. Когда пользователь пройдет тест, обработайте результат на сервере, сформируйте письмо и отправьте админу

Comment: в том то и вопрос. Можно ли это решить средствами JS\html без серверных языков, и самого сервера. Пока что страница на гитхабе размещается.

Comment: @ParkerRetro, а как вы письмо без сервера отправляете?

Comment: никак, пока выясняю возможность.е

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/mail/

Comment: @ParkerRetro, может, оформите бесплатный хостинг, закиньте серверные файлы туда. Когда пользователь перейдет по ссылке из письма, делайте `ajax` запрос на ваш бесплатный хостинг, который проверит, валидный ли токен. Если ответ положительный, то пусть пользователь выполняет тест (его содержимое так же можно подгрузить `ajax-ом`), а результаты снова шлите на ваш сервер. Боюсь, что чисто клиентским кодом не обойдетесь, т.к. ничто не мешает его отредактировать

Comment: @avengerweb SendMail() это server-side object.

Comment: @avengerweb
Возможно так и сделаю. Потому что более простых вариантов не вижу. Спасибо.

Comment: @ParkerRetro это не будет из браузера работать :)

Comment: Какой смысл клиенту отправлять письмо самому себе и самому себя авторизовывать тоненом (который для себя сгенерил)? На сколько я понимаю суть всех этих телодвижения с токеном в том что-бы убедиться что почта существует и принадлежит клиенту, перед тем как допустить его до теста. Тут нужно использовать серверный код. Можно вынести его на другой сервер и например тупо вставлять iframe с него в вашу страницу.

Answer (score -2):

На сервере в базу записываем случайный код типа dgfhg7fd5hfsjgj4534jgg

Высылаем код юзеру типа site.ru/kod/dgfhg7fd5hfsjgj4534jgg

При переходе юзера по ссылке проверяем есть ли код в базе если есть устанавливаем сессию для юзера и удаляем код из базы или меняем значение что типа он использован

Отправляем письмо на почту админу

Comment: Вы ответы читаете? В предыдущем написано то же самое, а в комментариях уточнение, что нужна реализация без серверной части